# Excel string concatenation and interpolation into formula

Tags: excel

Scenario:

I have two worksheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`

In one column I have an arbitrary column reference, call it `H:H` for example. I'd like to run the equivalent of the formula in `Column B` below, but without hardcoding `H:H` into the formula.

`Column A` | `Column B`
`H:H`      |  `=SUM(Sheet2!H:H)`

**Question:**
How can I interpolate the value of `Column A` and feed it into the formula in `Column B`?

*Attempt 1:* `=SUM(CONCATENATE("Sheet2!",INDIRECT("A2")))` - does not work
*Attempt 2:* `=SUM(CONCATENATE("Sheet2!",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))` - does not work

Note: this needs to be a non-VBA solution

Comment: in addition to @ScottCraner's `Indirect` answer, you could also take a different approach with `OFFSET`. For example, with `7` in `Column A` place this formula in `Column B`: `=SUM(OFFSET(Sheet2!A:A,0,A1))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'Sheet2'!" & A2))
```

If in A2 is H:H then it will sum the values in Column H on Sheet2.

Comment: Nice! I had to drop the single quotes around 'Sheet2!', but formatted like this it works: `=SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet2!" & A2))`

Comment: @tim5046 Sorry I had a single quote in the wrong place.  See edit.  It should have been before the `!`, I put the sigle quotes in to deal with sheet names that contain spaces.